# Weird XCodeColor behaviour when Red is larger than 100

Tags: xcode, plugins, xcodecolor

I've just installed the XCodeColor plugin into XCode7 and am experimenting with the output. I've hit a weird bug. When I use a large Red component the plugin fails to work. So this sequence is fine:

```
\033[fg:0,255,255; Hello     ===> Hello
```

But this fails:

```
\033[fg:255,255,255; Hello   ===> fg0,255,255; Hello
```

Anyone have any ideas why this is not working?

The Github site indicates that colour values up to 255 should be just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm. Not sure how, but now have it working after a refactor to do something else in the code base. I hate things that just "Fix themselves"!